# Wordpress plugin for multi level navigation menu's

Tags: navigation, wordpress

In drupal, we have http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus to create navigation menu's with multiple levels.

Does such a plugin exist for wordpress 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search ["dropdown menu" › WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=dropdown+menu&sort=). The new WP3 default theme Twenty Ten supports user configurable drop down menus.